# UIView won't stay resized after programmatic size change?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiview

I have a `UIViewController` with a `UIView` container within. I am resizing that container when an ad shows up on screen to account for the difference that the ad takes up on screen. The problem is that the view gets resized and then immediately changes back. I have attempted multiple things now with no success.

I have worked towards resizing the container view in the `viewDidLoad` method, but it doesn't do anything. I also tried setting the `self.view.autoresizesSubviews = NO;` My goal is to have the view animate the size change in the same method that my ad animates onto the screen. No matter what I do, though, the size changes will not stay.

Code that I am using to set the frame:

```
CGRect rectFrame = CGRectMake(self.tableViewController.frame.origin.x,
                                  self.tableViewController.frame.origin.y,
                                  self.tableViewController.frame.size.width,
                                  self.tableViewController.frame.size.height - 300);

self.tableViewController.frame = rectFrame;
```

Comment: i think when you're setting the frame that method calls up 2 times and first time it has correct value of frame and for second time it get back to default value so just log your object and you came to know about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because of auto layout, which is turned on by default. You either need to turn that off, or animate the size change by animating constraints, not setting frames. To animate a constraint to the bottom of the view, make an IBOutlet to it (I'll call it bottomCon), and modify its constant parameter:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
        self.bottomCon.constant = 300;
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    } completion:nil];
```

Comment: Could you give me an example of how I could edit the constraints? This particular view is constrained to the superview at the bottom. I just need that bottom constraint to be moved upwards the same height as the ad.

Comment: Thank you for the update. Something very strange is happening on these container view's. For some reason they have no constraints on them at all. I have autolayout on and constraint's are active on multiple other scenes, but not on these containers. Is there a reason for that? I have placed them in IB with guides, but they are not adding any constraints.

Comment: @Jonathan, what version of iOS are you using?

Comment: It's happening on both iOS 6 and iOS 7.

Comment: @Jonathan, I don't know how that can be -- I've never seen that in iOS 6. In iOS 7 you have to explicitly add them, but the system adds them for you in in iOS 6 (or at least it always has for me).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37142/discussion-between-rdelmar-and-jonathan)